# How can I correctly change the way a UITabBar appears using the appearance proxy?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, ios6

Since I am developing an iOS >= 5.0 application, I am trying to change the appearance of the main UI components through the appearance proxies.

When dealing with the `UITabBar` component, I correctly changed its `tintColor` to a light shade of gray trough the `[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:]` method. But doing this, the `UITabBarItem`s included in the bar are quite impossible to see, since they retain the old gray/white color in their title label.

I tried to change their appearance through the `[UITabBarItem appearance]` proxy, but there is no way to make them visible.

Can anyone suggest me a way to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi this will work for what you want to do

```
// Customize the UIBarButtonItem
    UIImage *button30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_textured_30"] 
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
    UIImage *button24 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_textured_24"] 
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button30 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button24 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor colorWithRed:82.0/255.0 
                      green:82.0/255.0
                       blue:82.0/255.0
                      alpha:1.0],                     UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [UIColor colorWithRed:242.0 
                      green:237.0 
                       blue:237.0 
                      alpha:1.0],                     UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0,1)],  UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:0.0],    UITextAttributeFont,nil]
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I thought the `setTitleTextAttributes:` method was only available on iOS >= 6.0. What do those two image look like?

Comment: These are used to set as the background image of button

Comment: I think you should change `UIBarButtonItem` with `UITabBarItem` for this solution to work.

Comment: Opps sorry for that may be this works fine with `UITabBarItem` also

Comment: Yes it does! Would you mind updating the answer, so I can accept it?